# SMTP recipient's server gives 5.0.0 Service unavailable for some messages but not for others [missing SRS?]

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I run a CentOS 7 sendmail SMTP server.  For some addresses (a@myclient.com), a virtusertable entry causes my server to forward messages addressed to that address to the client's ISP (charter.net) or gmail.  This works for 80-90% of the messages; but for other messages, charter.net or gmail reject the message with DSN 5.0.0 Service unavailable.  Note the DSN code is not 4.X.X, deferred, but 5.X.X, rejected.  I suspect this happens when the receiving server thinks the message is spam, but it sometimes happens on legitimate emails from, for example, the client's accountant.  It seems more likely to happen when there is an attachment to the email.

Does anyone know for sure why this happens?  What can I do to reduce the probability of legitmate email being rejected?  Might it help to set up SPF/DKIM/DMARC records for myclient.com?  For my server's canonical name (which it sends in EHLO records)?  Can a server add a DKIM signature to email it is only forwarding?

Thanks for your attention,
Bob

Comment: You need the complete rejection message from the recipient SMTP server, and AFAIK sendmail doesn't log it, only the minimal rejection code you see there. The rest of us switched to postfix long ago, and it _does_ log this data. Perhaps someone who kept up on sendmail knows how to make it log this.

Comment: In the age of SPF a mail server that provides email forwarding services should also do SRS to prevent SPF issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme

Comment: @HBruijn Could you recommend SRS recipe for sendmail?